# Формула конвертации времени в минутах во время в часах и минутах

Tags: excel-формулы

Имеется число минут например `150`.

С простой формулой `=FLOOR((D4/60); 0,1)` мы получим число в десятичном формате, что при не целом делении покажет `2.5` а не то что хотелось `2:30`.

Помогите с формулой, просто не знаю что тут можно использовать для решения вопроса.

Comment: CONCATENATE(FLOOR(A1/60;1);":";MOD(A1;60))

Comment: B1=A1/24/60. Формат ячейки = "ч:мм".

Answer (score 1):

В *Excel* дата хранится в виде целого числа - количества дней, начиная с 01.01.1900 года. Например, *26.12.2017 = 43095* (если ячейке с датой задать числовой или общий формат, можно увидеть десятичное представление даты)

И если 1 сутки - это 1 (единица), а время - часть суток, то совершенно правильный вывод: время - дробная часть десятичного числа.

```
1 час = 1/24
1 минута = 1/(24*60) = 1/24/60 = 1/1440   
1 секунда = =1/(24*60*60) = 1/24/60/60 = 1/86400
```

Зная это, десятичное число можно преобразовать во время - часы, минуты, секунды, разделив его на нужное число. При этом не забывая задавать нужный формат ячейки.

Иногда время необходимо показать текстом (например, в составе другого текста) Варианты текстового представления:

```
=ТЕКСТ(A1/1440;"чч:мм")

=ЦЕЛОЕ(A1/60)&":"&A1-ЦЕЛОЕ(A1/60)*60

=ЦЕЛОЕ(A1/60)&" ч. "&A1-ЦЕЛОЕ(A1/60)*60&" мин. "
```

В английской версии *ТЕКСТ - TEXT, ЦЕЛОЕ - INT*

Answer (score 0):

```
=FLOOR(D4/60)&":"&IIF(MOD(D4,60)<10,"0"&MOD(D4,60),MOD(D4,60))
```

Comment: Но не забывать, что формула выдаст текст. Если это и нужно, то оправдано===/ Да, ошибки не будет, если полученное значение сложить с числом, но перед суммированием *Excel* должен этот текст преобразовать в числовое значение. Это к тому, что данные должны храниться в правильных форматах: мухи к мухам, котлеты отдельно.

Comment: Так он и порсил текст же?

Comment: Возможно. И не отрицаю, что текстом в данном случае - правильно. Я оставил комментарий, который может помочь другим.

Comment: А, кстати, неправильно было. 0 забыл. Исправил.